# Docker with nginx-proxy: Additional Property Name is not allowed

Tags: docker

Docker stopped working after an upgrade from ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

I was using docker-compose but it completely stopped working. So I switched to "docker compose"

I am now trying to use

docker compose -f /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/compose-thestack.yml up -d

the error I am getting is..

`validating /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/compose-thestack.yml: services.mysql-yo2c.volumes.0 Additional property name is not allowed`

I suspect there are going to be more errors than just this.

The contents of the yml file that was previously working with docker-compose is.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    environment:
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      HSTS: 0
      DHPARAM_GENERATION: 0   
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/mods/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/domains/nginx/html
        target: /var/www/html
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/nginx.tmpl
        target: /app/nginx.tmpl
      - type: bind
        name: common
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts
        target: /common
    networks:
      nginx-proxy:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.254


##################################################################
  mysql-yo2c:
    depends_on:
      - "nginx-proxy"
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        name: db_yo2c
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/data_yo2c
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config 
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
    container_name: mysql-yo2c

##################################################################
  portainer:
    depends_on:
      - "nginx-proxy"
    image: portainer/portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/portainer/data:/data
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    container_name: portainer


##################################################################
# yo2c.com 
##################################################################
  yo2c-com:
    depends_on:
      - "mysql-yo2c"
    links:
      - "mysql-yo2c:mysqlhost"
    image: yo2c/php7_4_8_apache:v3
#    build:
#      context: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/mods
#      dockerfile: php_7.4.8-apache.RUN
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=yo2c.com,*.yo2c.com
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysqlhost
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wp_www_yo2c_com
      - DHPARAM_GENERATION=0
      - HTTPS_METHOD=redirect
      - HSTS=0
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/domains/www.yo2c.com:/var/www/html
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/domains/errors:/var/www/html/errors
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config
      - /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/php7/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker.ini
      - type: bind
        name: common
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts
        target: /common
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
    container_name: yo2c-com

networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/24
```

Docker seems to have changed so much in the last couple of years, I dont even know if we're still okay to use yml files and compose. Anyway, any help appreciated if you can tell me how to get these to load properly and correct me if nginx-proxy no longer works this way.

I am trying to use
`docker compose`
expecting it to work like `docker-compose`
but I am getting errors.

Comment: In Compose file format version 3, the [long form of `volumes:` entries](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-3) doesn't allow `name:`.  I'm not sure what that line would do, and you can just delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by changing the compose.yml to this...

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    environment:
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      HSTS: 0
      DHPARAM_GENERATION: 0   
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/mods/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf"
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/domains/nginx/html
        target: /var/www/html
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/nginx.tmpl
        target: /app/nginx.tmpl
    networks:
      nginx-proxy:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.0.254


##################################################################
  mysql-yo2c:
    depends_on:
      - "nginx-proxy"
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    volumes:
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/data_yo2c:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config" 
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
    container_name: mysql-yo2c

##################################################################
  portainer:
    depends_on:
      - "nginx-proxy"
    image: portainer/portainer
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/portainer/data:/data"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/certs:/etc/nginx/certs"
    container_name: portainer


##################################################################
# yo2c.com 
# Setup for PHP-7 / Mysql 5_7 Sites off the ketoric db server
##################################################################
  yo2c-com:
    depends_on:
      - "mysql-yo2c"
    links:
      - "mysql-yo2c:mysqlhost"
    image: yo2c/php7_4_8_apache:v3
#    build:
#      context: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/mods
#      dockerfile: php_7.4.8-apache.RUN
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=yo2c.com,*.yo2c.com
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysqlhost
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wp_www_yo2c_com
      - DHPARAM_GENERATION=0
      - HTTPS_METHOD=redirect
      - HSTS=0
    volumes:
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/domains/www.yo2c.com:/var/www/html"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/domains/errors:/var/www/html/errors"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts/config:/bin/config"
      - "/home/ubuntu/docker/configs/php7/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker.ini"
      - type: bind
        source: /home/ubuntu/docker/configs/scripts
        target: /common
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
    container_name: yo2c-com



networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/24
```

then I used this command.

`docker-compose -f compose-thestack.yml up -d --remove-orphans`

Note that I removed references to name: and moved the volume declarations into strings with full paths to the source.

nginx-proxy is still working perfectly with SSL certs on port 443